Pandas parquet file pyarrow.lib.ArrowMemoryError: malloc of size 106255424 failed
I am trying to run a python script in cPanel terminal. I am getting an error as the script tries to open the parquet file that is a 46.65 MB size. This worked on my home computer.
df = pd.read_parquet(file_path + 'CA_s.parquet')

The error message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.../my_script.py", line 60, in <module>
    df = pd.read_parquet(file_path + 'CA_s.parquet')
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/.../virtualenv/.../python3.11/.../pandas/io/parquet.py", line 667, in read_parquet
    return impl.read(
           ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/.../virtualenv/.../python3.11/.../pandas/io/parquet.py", line 281, in read
    result = pa_table.to_pandas(**to_pandas_kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pyarrow/array.pxi", line 885, in pyarrow.lib._PandasConvertible.to_pandas
  File "pyarrow/table.pxi", line 5002, in pyarrow.lib.Table._to_pandas
  File "/home/.../virtualenv/.../python3.11/.../pyarrow/pandas_compat.py", line 784, in table_to_dataframe
    result = pa.lib.table_to_blocks(options, table, categories,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pyarrow/table.pxi", line 3941, in pyarrow.lib.table_to_blocks
  File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 92, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowMemoryError: malloc of size 106255424 failed

I typed free -m in terminal to get the memory data:




total
used
free
shared
buff/cache
available




Mem:
15507
5497
2561
1209
7447
7588


Swap:
1023
811
212






Please share any ideas or answers thanks.

Are you running this in a VM with limited RAM?

@TimRoberts, Yes it is a VM with limited Ram but it should be enough. I'll add this detail to the question.

Never the less, that's what it says.  You might want to do some memory instrumentation to see what else you are loading.  Pandas, my itself, is a very large package.
